# Android Studio [Navigation Drawer] / onClick Listener ¿Por qué no puedo cambiar de Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Como bien saben, **Android Studio** nos permite crear un **Navigation Drawer** con tan solo unos pocos clics. Por defecto, esta actividad que creamos, posee el **código interno** necesario para cambiar de fragment al tocar algún **Item**. Yo estoy intentando capturar los **clics a estos items** para (por medio de mi propio código) **cambiar** al fragment que corresponda. Lo que intenté, por alguna razón, no funciona. Mi aplicación **no crashea** ni nada por el estilo. Simplemente, al tocar clic en mi Item perfil, la acción que deriva de este clic es llevarme al **fragment que creó android studio** por defecto el cual está relacionado a ese item, **en lugar de llevarme al que yo le indiqué en el código**.

¿Que puedo hacer para que se deje de cambiar de Fragment por defecto para empezar a tratarlo yo con código?.

***Esto es lo que intenté:***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

 private NavController nc, nc2;
 private DrawerLayout drawer;
 private NavigationView nv;
 private AppBarConfiguration abc;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    nv = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    abc = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_inicio, R.id.nav_perfil, R.id.nav_chat,
            R.id.nav_favoritos, R.id.nav_buscar,
            R.id.nav_configuracion, R.id.nav_ayuda)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    nc = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(nv, nc);
 }

 //MÉTODO ONCLICK DE LOS ITEMS
 @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    switch(id){
        case R.id.nav_chat:         
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Prueba",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
//CÓDIGO QUE NO ME FUNCIONA AL TOCAR EL ITEM PERFIL.
        case R.id.nav_perfil:
                fragment_contenedor_chat fragment = new 
                fragment_contenedor_chat();

              fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment)
              .commit();
              break;}
    return true;}}
```

> **ACLARACIÓN:** Quiero controlar los fragments por mi cuenta porque quiero que la app redireccione al usuario a distintos fragments según el tipo de usuario que esté interactuando con la app. Fragment perfil para usuarios "Encargados" o fragment perfil para usuarios "Administrador". (Sería un mismo item perfil pero que lleva a distintos fragments según quien esté interactuando)

Comment: Nadie sabe como resolver este problema?

Comment: no entiendo que quieres hacer

Comment: Gracias por leer @armen . Muy amable de tu parte. Quiero lograr que el usuario pueda ingresar a diferentes fragmentos dependiendo de que tipo de usuario sea. Ejemplo: En mi app hay usuarios que son "Encargados" y otros "Administradores". El navigation drawer tiene un item llamado perfil. Me gustaría que al tocar ese item perfil, el usuario sea redireccionado al perfil "Encargado" o al perfil "Administrador" según le corresponda. Si no me expliqué muy bien, podríamos chatear?