# Android Studio / Enviar datos desde una actividad a un fragment que está dentro de un Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragment, navigation

**(Voy a ser MUY específico para evitar dudas y porque realmente necesito solucionar este problema. Perdón por la extensión de la pregunta)**

Mi aplicación empieza mostrando el primer fragmento de un **navigation Drawer** (Home).
Dentro de este fragmento hay un botón que se llama "**Actividad**" el cuál me redirecciona a una actividad por lo que quedo **fuera** del nav drawer.

La actividad posee dos Edit Texts (**Nombre** y **Apellido**) y un botón que se llama "**Enviar datos**" para enviar los datos de vuelta al primer fragmento de el navigation drawer (**Home**).

Para lograr el traspaso de datos desde la activity hacia el fragment estoy probando con **dos formas distintas** (las cuales no me están dando los resultados deseados) las cuales voy a explicar a detalle:

El primer método que utilizo es el uso de Bundle el cual por alguna razón no funciona. No recibe los datos.

**Adjunto el método que le pongo al botón "Enviar Datos" que toma los datos desde la actividad y luego la cierra para volver al fragmento "Home":**

```
public void enviarDatos(){
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("a","tomas");
   fragment_inicio f = new fragment_inicio();
   f.setArguments(bundle);
   finish();
}
```

Una vez clickeado el botón, se vuelve al fragmento "Home" donde se deberían capturar los datos (situación que no ocurre). **Adjunto el código:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if(bundle != null){
        String nombre = bundle.getString("a");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), nombre, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
return view;
}
```

Como esto no me funcionó, decidí probar con **SharedPreferences**. Con esto solo obtengo un problema cuando presiono el botón "**Enviar datos**", porque al presionarlo no se lanza la acción que deseo (Enviar un Toast) pero si que se **queda guardado** el registro en las preferencias. Esto quiere decir que si cierro la aplicación y la vuelvo a abrir, la app detecta que ya **fueron guardados** datos en las preferencias y termina por mostrar el Toast.

Me gustaría que el Toast se muestre en el fragment cuando le doy al botón desde la actividad y no teniendo que "refrescar" el fragment.

**Adjunto el código del botón "Enviar Datos" de la actividad**

```
public void enviarDatos(){
   SharedPreferences prefs = 
   getSharedPreferences("Preferencias",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
   editor.putString("a","Tom");
   editor.commit();
   finish();
}
```

**Adjunto el código del fragment que recibe la preferencia**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inicio, container, false);

SharedPreferences prefs = 
getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Preferencias",0);
    String nombre = prefs.getString("a","error");
    if(nombre != "error"){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), nombre, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No llegaron los datos", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

return view;}
```

Comment: el envio de datos debe ser entre activities, una vez obtenido en activity se envia con bundle al fragment. No puedes enviar directamente de una Activity a un Fragment de otra Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con intent se envian datos entre activities. De una Activity a un fragment (que pertenece
a la misma Activity) se usa bundle.
Te dejo un ejemplo.

En la Activity2, que es donde capturas los editText y suponiendo que los
EditText se llaman nombre y apellido, envias los datos con `intent putExtra`:

```
 botonEnviarDatos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String n = nombre.getText().toString().trim();
            String a = apellido.getText().toString().trim();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, ActivityNavDrawer.class);
            intent.putExtra("nombre", n);
            intent.putExtra("apellido", a);
            startActivity(intent);  // se inicia otra Activity y se le envían datos
            finish();
        }
    });
```

En la ActivityNavDrawer, dentro de onCreate, recibes los datos con `Bundle getIntent`, y los envias
al fragment_inicio con `bundle putString`:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras !=null){
        String value1 = extras.getString("nombre");  
        String value2 = extras.getString("apellido");  

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("nombre", value1);
        bundle.putString("apellido", value2);

  // si estas usando la antigua forma de navegacion de fragments:
        FragmentInicio f = new FragmentInicio();
        f.setArguments(bundle);      // aquí envías los datos al fragment
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame, f).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    // si estas usando la nueva forma de navegacion de fragments, sería así:
        Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.fragment_inicio, bundle);
     }
```

Lo recibes en el fragment, en onCreateView:

```
  if (getArguments() != null) {
        nn = getArguments().getString("nombre");
        aa = getArguments().getString("apellido");
    }else {           // para evitar un NPE:
        nn = "";
        aa = "";
    }
   textView.setText(nn+" "+aa);   ....
```

Comment: NO LO PUEDO CREER! Pudiste solucionar este GRAN problema que tanto me estaba haciendo ruido en la cabeza. En serio que estoy muy agradecido. No solo que podré seguir avanzando sino que aprendí algo que me va a ser de muchisima utilidad .GRACIAS.  No quisiera molestar pero me gustaría que me expliques dos cosas: 1- .addToBackStack (¿para que es?) 2- La segunda forma de navegar no la conozco. A que te refieres con ese "Navigation" del principio? Me gustaría aprenderla porque es solo 1 línea de código.

Comment: se me olvidaba también pedirte si por favor podrías leer esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/319054/android-studio-navigation-drawer-onclick-listener-por-qu%c3%a9-no-puedo-cambiar Gracias nuevamente :)