# Enviar datos de una Actividad a un Fragment dentro de esa actividad

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Estoy intentado hacer una aplicación en la que uso dos Activity, de la primera (una especie de login), paso a la segunda Activity, que contiene dos Fragment, cada uno con un ListView. Bien, pues necesito que lo que introduzca en la primera Activity, se mande a uno de los Fragment de la segunda Activity, pero no consigo hacerlo, me tira fallo siempre, y no sé por qué.

He intentado muchas cosas antes de recurrir a pedir ayuda, ya que es un tema recurrente, pero no me ha funcionado nada, ni con Bundle, ni con una Interface, ni con métodos, nada... Agradecería muchísimo un cable, porque no hay manera...

El código es el siguiente:

La Activity principal:

```
package com.example.chat;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText input_nickname, input_servidor, input_puerto;
Button enviar;
Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    input_nickname = findViewById(R.id.input_nickname);
    input_servidor = findViewById(R.id.input_servidor);
    input_puerto = findViewById(R.id.input_puerto);
    enviar = findViewById(R.id.button_main);

    enviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AppActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("nickname", input_nickname.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("servidor", input_servidor.getText().toString());
            i.putExtra("puerto", Integer.parseInt(input_puerto.getText().toString()));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    }
}
```

La Activity 2, donde tengo los dos Fragment y donde guardo lo que me llega de la Activity 1, para luego pasárselo al Fragment:

```
package com.example.chat;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class AppActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String nickname, servidor;
private int puerto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app);

    nickname = getIntent().getStringExtra("nickname");
    servidor = getIntent().getStringExtra("servidor");
    puerto = getIntent().getIntExtra("puerto", 60001);
}
}
```

El Fragment al que le quiero hacer llegar los datos (en la que ahora mismo no hay nada porque no he conseguido hacer que funcione, ni con Bundle, ni con una Interface, ni con métodos en la segunda Activity, nada):

```
package com.example.chat;


import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;

private String nickname, servidor;
private int puerto;

private ArrayList<Mensaje> mensajes = new ArrayList<>();

public ChatFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    listView = getView().findViewById(R.id.listvview_mensajes);
    MensajesAdapter adapter = new MensajesAdapter(this, mensajes);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Estas segudo que con "ni con una Interface" has logrado realizarlo? era lo que iba a recomendarte. Es importante agregar que error es el que obtienes en el LogCat.

Comment: ya hay respuestas. Ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320804/android-studio-enviar-datos-desde-una-actividad-a-un-fragment-que-est%c3%a1-dentro/320927#320927

Answer (score 1):

Para pasar datos a un Fragment, el Fragment debe guardar los datos en un Bundle y después devolver la instancia para que la Activity haga la navegación.

Para ésto, te adapto la solución oficial de Android developer a tu caso en particular, dónde la Activity 2 ya recibe un bundle.  Hay que hacerlo a través de un método estático porque por defecto el constructor de Fragment no admite parámetros:

Java:

```
 class ChatFragment extends Fragment() {

      public static ChatFragment getInstance(bundle: Bundle) {
        ChatFragment fragment = ChatFragment()
        fragment.arguments(bundle)

        return fragment()
      }
    }
```

Kotlin:

```
class ChatFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun instance(bundle: Bundle): ChatFragment = ChatFragment().apply { 
            arguments = bundle
        }
    }
}
```

Si en el futuro empleas la Navigation, la forma de pasar los datos cambia.