# pasar varible de un activity a un fragment Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragment, kotlin, activity, navigation-drawer

Pido por favor si me pueden ayudar, hice una activity con Navigation Drawer Activity en Android Studio con Kotlin, ya he logrado pasar variable entre los fragment pero no he logrado entre el activity y el primer Fragment. como puedo realizar esta transacción teniendo en cuenta que es en kotlin.

Muchas gracias

Comment: eso se hace con bundle, aquí un ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320804/android-studio-enviar-datos-desde-una-actividad-a-un-fragment-que-est%c3%a1-dentro/320927#320927

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, estoy trabajando con kotlin y si pasa ya la variable pero me genera un error que no me deja visualizar el menú desplegable, este es el código:

Answer (score 0):

cuando hago lo que me dices me genera un error, mira mi código

```
private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private val bundle = Bundle()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin)
    val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val intent = intent
    val iEmail = intent.getStringExtra("email")
    val iKey = intent.getStringExtra("key")


    bundle.putString("iKey",iKey)


    val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }
    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.nav_home,bundle)

     // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow
        ), drawerLayout
    )
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, this.appBarConfiguration)  // aquí me dice el error
    navView.setupWithNavController(navController) // aqui igual me marca error
}
```

Comment: Esto debe ir en tu pregunta amigo y no como respuesta

Comment: que pena no sabia, gracias