# Crear elementos tipo “one to many” en Room y visualizarlos en otro activity o fragment en Android

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos

Estoy diseñando una app en android que a partir de la creación de una entidad esta se visualizada a mediante un fragment con view model. el problema es que luego de hacer intent sobre uno de los elementos del Adapter y pasando el extra con

```
"Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityAreaDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",holder.mItem.getId());"
```

Me lleva al otro activity recibiendo el entero de la clave primaria del objeto a travez de

```
"int idArea = getIntent().getIntExtra("id")"
```

pero no he logrado Anidarlo con el identificador del objeto seleccionado.

ya cree la relación entre los objetos
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships?hl=es-419.
Pero no se como debo llevar la clave primaria del primer objeto hacia el segundo. no se si se debe hacer través del viewmodel, con un intent o con un bundle. una cosa mas en el nuevo fragment siempre recibo `savedInstanceState==null.`

Comment: para enviar datos a una Activity es con intent putExtra, para un Fragment es con bundle: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/320804/android-studio-enviar-datos-desde-una-actividad-a-un-fragment-que-est%c3%a1-dentro/320927#320927

Comment: Hola! Porque no le pasas todo el objeto, para esto solo bastaría con convertir tu objeto a Parcelable si es que no lo está.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el compañero convierte tu objeto a parcelable y envíalo en el intent, [hay plugins que te lo autogeneran](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7332-android-parcelable-code-generator).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ActivityAreaDetails.class);
Foo foo = new Foo();
intent.putExtra("foo ", foo);
startActivity(intent);
```

Para recuperarlo:

```
Foo foo = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("foo");
```